# Transactions with ASP.NET Core 1.0 Identity UserManager

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-identity

In one of my apps, I'm rewriting Asp Core Identity UserManager's CreateAsync, to in addition to creating new user in UserStore - create a new row in a separate statistics table (on a different dbcontext). Problem is, I would like both of those operations to be fired inside a transaction, so that if one fails - the other does not commit. Here's the code :

```
public override async Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(TUser user, string password)
    {
        // We need to use transactions here.            
            var result = await base.CreateAsync(user, password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var appUser = user as IdentityUser;

                if (appUser != null)
                {
                    // create user stats.
                    var userStats = new UserStats()
                    {
                        ActionsCount = 0,
                        EventsCount = 0,
                        FollowersCount = 0,
                        ProjectsCount = 0,
                        UserId = appUser.Id
                    };

                    _ctx.UserStats.Add(userStats);
                    await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
            }    
            return result;
    }
```

Thing is, I have no idea how to set up such a transaction, as it seems TransactionScope is not a part of .Net Core yet (?) and getting currently scoped DbContext for base.CreateAsync() with HttpContext.GetOwinContext() does not work as HttpContext seems to be missing this method (referencing Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb or Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin as hinted in some other stack overflow answers won't do - both are not compatible with .netcore). Any help ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly you need to setup the dbcontext you are using with identity with a scoped lifetime:

```
        services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(ServiceLifetime.Scoped); // this is the important bit

        services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(options =>
        {
        })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext, int>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Then when you need to create a transaction you do the following:

```
        using (var transaction = await _myDbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync())
        {
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, password);

            try
            {
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    DBItem newItem = new DBItem();
                    _myDbContext.Add(newItem);

                    await _myDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
```

Comment: great stuff ! Thank you for this direction, seems like it might be the way to go if only I can configure the Scoped lifetime, it seems that in EF 1.0.0-rc2-final , AddDbContext doesn't have a method taking ServiceLifetime and doesn't allow you to setup Transient / Scoped lifetime for DbContext and I can't upgrade to 1.0.0 since it breakes my app so will have to wait to see if this works.

Comment: I've registered both of the contexts like so :

Comment: I've registered both of the contexts like so : 

 services.AddScoped<RezonateContext>();
        services.AddScoped<IdentityContext>();

but still, await base.CreateAsync(user, password); doesnt care about the transaction scope.

Comment: Having a look at the AddDbContext source it does something slightly different than just addscoped, have a look at lines 152,153,155 here:https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/03bcb5122e3f577a84498545fcf130ba79a3d987/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.cs

Comment: I've made a hack around TryAdd so dirty I had to take a shower afterwards, and it seems that both contexts are registered scoped now, but alas - CreateAsync still doesn't care about the transaction :(

Comment: That's no good! Are you sure there's no way to upgrade to 1.0.0 - not upgrading now might just cause more headaches in the future?

Comment: There will come a time I will have to :) For now I've dug a bit and did a bit of a hack and implemented my own UserStore that exposes a BeginTransaction method (UserStore has a property to access it's Context, but only as protected - for a reason) that starts a transaction on it's internal context , and use it in CreateAsync , so I end up with transaction inside transaction and commit or roll back both.

Comment: `transaction.Rollback()` in the catch block is not required because it is called automatically when leaving the using statement and `transaction.Commit()` was not called before.