# How to rollback changes in ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need help with my code.
Currently in my ASP.NET Core 2 application, I create user this way:

```
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);
```

If succeeded I add user to roles and I do some other operations on database.

```
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
           var roleResult = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user,"Admin");
           if(roleResult.Succeeded)
           {
            await _repository.AddToGroup("External");
            await _repository.AssignToRoom(RoomEnum.Office);
           }
        }
```

If for some reason **AddToGroup()** or **AssignToRoom()** will not be succeeded, user should not be created and should not be added to roles as well.
I would like to undo createing user operation completly.
How to achive that?

Comment: Have you tried using TransactionScope?

Comment: @Mt. Schneiders I tried but could not do that working. Could you help?

Comment: Why don't you delete him if anything goes wrong?

Comment: @dcg I can't delete user, because other related rows were created.

Comment: Please note guys, that these are async operations.

Comment: The way you currently have it set up you would have to create a method in your _userManager to remove the user if any of the other conditions fail. This will have to undo the create/insert statements up until point of failure

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38782721/944474) answer gives an example of how to use transactions for these kinds of operations. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `TransactionScope` class. Using this class you will have `Commit` or `Rollback` methods which will help you to commit the whole transaction or rollback the whole transaction.

read more about `TransactionScope`:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope?view=netframework-4.8
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/transactions#combining-several-operations-into-one-transaction-within-the-same-context